# How to pass many inputs from one html to another page

Tags: html, jsp

I have a html page which takes the inputs datetime1,datetime2,moteid and has a submit button,which should redirect to another page on the onclick of submit button.
I want to use the inputs here,that were given in the previous page ie.,datetime1,datetime2,moteid

```
         var d1=document.getElementById("datetime1").value;
         var d2=document.getElementById("datetime2").value;
         var m=document.getElementById("moteid").value;
         **var newwindow = parent.window.open("pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime1="+d1+"&"+"pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime2="+d2+"&"+"pdf1jsp.jsp?moteid="+m);
         //var newwindow = parent.window.open("pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime1="+d1+"pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime2="+d2+"pdf1jsp.jsp?moteid="+m);**


window.close();
```

When i give only one input,then its fine and i'm getting the output

```
var newwindow = parent.window.open("pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime1="+d1);
```

How to pass many inputs .What is the wrong with the above syntax

Answer (score 0):

Passing values from page to page is not a good practice. Since you already have a `jsp`, you should starting passing the value from your `jsp` to a `Servlet`. 
Your fields should be inside a `form`. Then point the `action` attribute of that form to the `Servlet`. Have those values validated there, then pass them again to another `jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

use QueryStrings:

```
var newwindow = parent.window.open("pdf1jsp.jsp?datetime1="+document.getElementById("datetime1").value+"&"+...);
```

Then get the values from result page